# What mechanism is used to update the view with angular mvvm pattern?

Tags: html, angularjs, mvvm, angular, websocket

I'm in the research step of a web-project and want to decide whether to use jquery+signalr or Angular and its mvvm pattern for realtime communication between Server and Client.

As I found out, SignalR tries to setup a websocket connection between server and client. If that doesn't work, HTML-longpolling oder ForeverFrame is used instead.
This behaviour is absulutely nice to have.

But as mentioned, I'm looking on Angular, too. It is absolutely a relevant alternative framework to jQuery (from my point of view).
Since I have some experience on C# and WPF, I'm familiar with the mvvm pattern.
But I can't figure out with what mechanism (websockets, longpolling, ...) Angular does send the data from a server to the view elements of its clients, that have a databinding on a viewmodel whose data was changed.

I appreciate any hint or complete answer to this question :)
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: AngularJs (1) have a Ng-Model and $scope for two-data-binding.
here you find documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 is there to build apps and these apps are fully running on the client-side.
In a browser, or an mobile-app (using nativescript) or a desktop-app (using electron).

The model, the view and the controller are on the client-side..

If you want to communicate with an backend server, you have to do it with http requests or for realtime you can even use SignalR or socket.io..

There is no built-in support for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This clears my lack of crompehension where the mvvm pattern is actually  settled.

I will now move forward to investigate a combination of Angular and SignalR compared to jQuery and SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR gives you an infrastruture that you can send messages from server to client and from client to server. 
The "limitation" is that you have to write your server part in C#.NET. But the client can be a C#(WPF, Winforms,..), or Java- or also a Javascript-Client.

If you're plannung to write your application with AngularJS, there is an angularjs module which does some work for you: 
https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub

If you are plannung an application which only update data on user input, you will not require signalR. But if you require server push (means if you're writing an application which updates data in client on an event on server) you can use signalr .